# SQL to get equally represented rows for a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgres table

| job | task | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| j1 | t1 | s1 |
| j1 | t2 | s1 |
| j1 | t11 | s1 |
| j1 | t21 | s1 |
| j1 | t3 | s2 |
| j2 | t4 | s1 |
| j2 | t5 | s1 |
| j2 | t41 | s1 |
| j2 | t51 | s1 |
| j2 | t6 | s2 |
| j3 | t7 | s1 |
| j3 | t8 | s1 |
| j3 | t71 | s1 |
| j3 | t81 | s1 |
| j3 | t9 | s2 |

I want to get 6 tasks which has s1 status. I want to ensure that j1, j2 and j3 are equally represented.

Wanted Output:-

| job | task | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| j1 | t1 | s1 |
| j1 | t2 | s1 |
| j2 | t4 | s1 |
| j2 | t5 | s1 |
| j3 | t7 | s1 |
| j3 | t8 | s1 |

How should I structure my query ?

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: How do decide which one to pick when there are two (or more)? Can you explain what "*represented enough*" actually means?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Your results appear to be simply the min() task of each job...?

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question to make it more clearer. I need the result to not just have 1 (max or first) representation. I need it contain equal representation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to add a [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), numbering rows from each `job` separately, then order by that, you'll be getting equal amount of records from each `job` when you finally [`limit 6`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vrqNNuDY)

```
select job,task,status,row_number()over(partition by job) as rn
from test where status='s1'
order by rn 
limit 6;
```

| job | task | status | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| j1 | t1 | s1 | 1 |
| j3 | t7 | s1 | 1 |
| j2 | t4 | s1 | 1 |
| j1 | t2 | s1 | 2 |
| j3 | t8 | s1 | 2 |
| j2 | t5 | s1 | 2 |

Comment: Will this handle larger data sets, including j4, j5, ... j_n_?

Comment: It does: [here's a test](https://dbfiddle.uk/2Y39VCXj) on 600k records with 1k different jobs. On 90M on my machine it works well, too. At some point it becomes pointless, when few enough records are requested out of a very large dataset - if it's sparse enough that it's statistically unlikely to get the same job twice, a [`tablesample` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) would be enough. Depends on the distribution, but at some point it could make sense to `tablesample` first, and use the above to only discard the surplus in the sample.